# In Homogenous Differential equations, is $v+ x\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}x$ is equal to $1/ (v + y\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}y)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the analysis of homogeneous ordinary differential equations, you can either substitute $y=vx$ or $x=vy$. If $y=vx$, then 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}= v + x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x},
$$
and if $x= vy$, then 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}= v + y\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}y}.
$$

> So can I say that $v+ x\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x} \text{ is equal to } \big(v + y\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}y}\big)^{-1}$?

Also, I have found that using $x=vy$ as a substitute gives a much complicated solution than using $y=vx$.

> So does this mean that the solution that we get by using each of these substitutions are the same, or are they different solutions? And when should we use $x=vy$ as opposed to $y=vx$?

Answer (score 1):

Well those two expressions are equal, but do notice that v means different things in the different substitution. That is, it’s better to say that y=ux and x=vy. 
Besides, in differential equations of 1 order, x and y share the same position, generally. But in different situation the complexity may change. It all depends.

Comment: What do you mean by x and y sharing the same position?  Also, in first order differential equations, will the solution we get by using y=vx  and the solution we get by using x=vy be the same? Or will it be different? Because what I've noticed is that when using x=vy, my solution is completely different to the solution I get when using y=vx. No matter how much I try to change its form, I still couldn't get it to equal.

Comment: @Fourth If $y=ux$ and $x=vy$, then $uv=1$. The solution in terms of just $x$ and $y$ should be the same (up to a constant) for any method of solution, but written in terms of $x$ and $u$ or in terms of $y$ and $v$, it may look quite different.